# GCP Load Balancer High Availability

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, google-cloud-platform

What is required to have HTTP HA load balancing using GCP's load balancers? Should I setup two ore more load balancers pointing to the same backends? I can't find a way to define what zones the load balancers reside in, which makes me think that the load balancers are HA by default, but I haven't seen it explicitly stated in the documentation.

Edit: This is regarding HTTP load balancing.

Comment: The exact answer is going to depend a bit on what protocol you intend to be using and what capabilities your clients have. If your service is reachable through two different IP addresses and clients are able to automatically fail over between them if one is not responding you can get better reliability than is achievable with only a single IP address.

Comment: It's also going to make a difference which kind of GCP load balancing you choose. The HTTP and TCP load balancing are for example quite different.

Comment: Edited question to reflect HTTP load balancing.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTTP Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) is a Global resource, which means they do not reside in a single zone. You don't need to take any specific steps to have it be High Availability, having multiple LB or multiple frontends pointing to the same backends is not necessary.

You will want to have multiple back-ends with good health checks configured(or a single backend with multiple instances). Ideally, you will want to use a [Managed Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) to allow Autoscalling as well.

The main cause of downtime with HTTP(S) Load Balancers is caused by unhealthy or misconfigured backends.